# SQL: Select Duplicate Values using Distinct, Not Exists, CTE, Union

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, union, common-table-expression, not-exists

I need to select duplicate values highlighted in green from the Object table show below: 
[image: Object table]

I've tried different combination of the code below. But cannot return the two duplicate rows.

```
;with CTE as
    (Select distinct ID, count([Object ID]) as [Object ID] 
from #Object 
     group by ID having count([Object ID]) > 1)

select * from CTE where 
    NOT EXISTS (Select distinct ID , count(distinct [Object ID]) as [Object ID] 
from #Object group by ID having count(distinct [Object ID]) > 1);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the window function ROW_NUMBER() to identify duplicate rows.

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,ObjectID int,ObjectName varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
(250708,321,'hotel'),
(250708,343,'mercantile'),
(250708,370,'parking'),
(250708,370,'residential condominium'),
(250708,370,'residential condominium'),
(250708,401,'residential condominium'),
(250708,401,'residential condominium')



;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,RN = Row_Number() over ( Partition By ID,ObjectID,ObjectName Order by (Select NULL))
     From  @YourTable
)
Select * 
 From cte 
 Where RN>1
```

Returns

[image]

On a side-note, you can delete these records by replacing the final `Select *` with `DELETE`

Comment: This will miss the first row in any set of duplicates.

Comment: @MartinSmith Only the second dupe is highlighed

Comment: @MartinSmith Encouraging to know that can happen to someone of your ranking and reputation.  :)

Comment: John, you put have to remove parentheses after NULL and place two once aster "YourTable" .

Comment: John, also when I parse the code it says: Command(s) completed successfully. But when I actually execute it is says: 1. Must specify table to select from. invalid columns names.... 2. Invalid column name 'ID',  Invalid column name 'Object ID'... 3.  Invalid column name 'Object Name', 4. No column name was specified for column 1 of 'cte'

Comment: John, you also missed the From clause after the Order By

Comment: @enigma6205 No I did not. The window functions are invaluable.  Well worth your time to get comfortable with them.

Comment: John, also your Order BY does not make sense at it returns more than 1 value. Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the correct edition of the code in the first answer

```
;With cte as (
        Select *
              ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By ID, [Object ID] Order by (Select NULL))
       From tblObject 
     )

    Select *
     From cte 
     Where RN>1;
```

Comment: Well done! +1  Just a hint for the future.  It is more helpful if you post sample data as text which can me copied and pasted rather than the image.  This way we can test the SQL for proper field names and/or syntax,